Migrate Jetty server from 9 to 11 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: STARTING error
When we run the Java Spring MVC application with Jakarta servlet 5.0+ & Jetty 11 server then we are getting below error, could you help to find the root cause for this issue.

[com.webapp.authentication.ServerMain.main()] INFO
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-11.0.23; built:
2024-08-14T01:40:17.906Z; git:
6fcf5ccaebd7ca13a0cb96c96adca699a24080a0; jvm 11.0.19+9-LTS-224
[com.webapp.authentication.ServerMain.main()] WARN
org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext - Failed startup of context
o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@71fbe483{} java.lang.IllegalStateException:
STARTING  at
org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:128)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ListenerHolder.doStart(ListenerHolder.java:73)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:382)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1305)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:902)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:306)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:533)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:470)   at
org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:415)     at
org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
at com.webapp.authentication.ServerMain.main(ServerMain.java:63)    at
org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:254)  at
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[com.webapp.authentication.ServerMain.main()] INFO
org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started
ServerConnector@64f2b93c{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
[com.webapp.authentication.ServerMain.main()] INFO
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started
Server@4ae47b7{STARTING}[11.0.23,sto=0] @20551ms

Here is the POM I used,
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1</version>

    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>CAT</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <appengine-sdk-version>2.0.25</appengine-sdk-version>
        <gcloud.plugin.version>0.9.58.v20150505</gcloud.plugin.version>
        <spring-version>5.3.24</spring-version>
        <spring-security-version>5.6.10</spring-security-version>
        <spring-data-jpa-version>2.7.6</spring-data-jpa-version>
        <hibernate-version>6.2.0.Final</hibernate-version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
        <jetty>11.0.23</jetty>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <mainClass>com.webapp.authentication.ServerMain</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.3.3</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <appengine.application>gcp</appengine.application>
                <appengine.version>dev</appengine.version>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <filters>
                    <filter>src/main/resources/profiles/local.properties</filter>
                </filters>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        

        <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine-sdk-version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.transaction-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>4.12.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
            <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-jpa-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-openid</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.inject-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>apacheds-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-M20</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20240303</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.json</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>v2-rev157-1.25.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <version>${jetty}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
            <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.14</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>


        <outputDirectory>
            ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                            <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <stage.enableJarSplitting>true</stage.enableJarSplitting>
                    <deploy.stopPreviousVersion>true</deploy.stopPreviousVersion>
                    <deploy.projectId>gcp</deploy.projectId>
                    <deploy.version>${appengine.version}</deploy.version>
                    <deploy.service>cat</deploy.service>
                    <port>8080</port>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${jetty}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>

Server.Main()class I used,
package com.webapp.authentication;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

import org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.PathResource;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;


@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.webapp.*"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.webapp.entity.*"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.webapp.repository.*")
public class ServerMain {
    
    public static final String WEBAPP_RESOURCES_LOCATION = "target/CAT-1/resources"; 

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class", "org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StrErrLog");
        System.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL", "INFO");

        Server server = new Server(8080);
        
        Path baseResource = new File("src/main/webapp").toPath().toRealPath();
        Path classesDir = new File("target/CAT-1/WEB-INF/classes").toPath();

        if (!Files.exists(baseResource))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Unable to find Base Resource Dir: " + baseResource);
        if (!Files.exists(classesDir))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Unable to find Classes Dir: " + classesDir);

        WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
        webAppContext.setContextPath("/");
        webAppContext.setDescriptor("target/CAT-1/WEB-INF/web.xml");
        webAppContext.setBaseResource(new PathResource(baseResource.toAbsolutePath()));
        webAppContext.setExtraClasspath(classesDir.toAbsolutePath().toString());
        webAppContext.setParentLoaderPriority(true);

        server.setHandler(webAppContext);

        server.start();

        server.join();
      }
}


Something called either WebAppContext.stop() or Server.stop() while the Server was starting.
That's all that means, and without more details (debug logs, your codebase, etc) it will be very difficult to point to a specific thing causing it.

I have updated complete POM file and Server Main class file. Please check and let me know any further file is needed.
